# iOS IPA installation over the air using google drive

Tags: ios, xcode, google-drive-api, release

I am trying to upload a ipa and manifest file to google drive and share it via email as a link.

I am able to do this with dropbox and it works perfectly

I think the problem is with google drive sharing methods

when we share we get

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing

I tried converting the the link to below format and still didn't work.

> itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=preview&id=FILE_ID

Note:
*I cannot use dropbox due to some constraints from my company.*

Answer (score 0):

Change `preview` to `download`:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

Google Drive usually gives you links to a HTML page with information about the file and a download button. You need a direct file link.

Also make sure to make the file public.